# What are the differences between Single Stage, Dual Stage and Reverse Osmosis Under Sink Water Filters?

Tags: water, kitchens, sink, filter

I'm looking to buy and install an under sink water filter - How do Single Stage, Dual Stage and Reverse Osmosis types compare?

Comparing:

- Taste/Odor
- Contaminants Removed
- Filter Maintenance/Replacement
- Price
- Ease of installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single versus dual stage is easy; dual stage is essentially two single-stage filters in succession. Bulkier, more expensive. Better removal of contaminants. Installation is the same.

Reverse osmosis is an entirely different technology. It generally has a prefilter because RO doesn't deal with particulates, only dissolved chemicals. It does handle those very well. It works by using pressure and a semipermiable membrane to achieve the purification. The membrane lasts a long time, but the system uses additional water to concentrate the impurities and flush them away so there's some ongoing cost there. Installation is a bit more complicated as well.